# The relation of your cousin’s cousin

Tags: kinship-terms

My aunt Diana is married to a man named Evens, he’s legally my uncle. They have two daughters named Daili and Diane whom are my cousins. Daili and Diane have a cousin named Daniela who is Evers niece. Is there a relation between me and Daniela? I’m assuming we’re not related but I’m just curious if there is a term.

Comment: She's your cousins' cousin, there isn't any name more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

As she is not a relative by blood (or even, really, by marriage as a step-sister would be) then there almost certainly isn't a term for your relationship. Having said that the word *cousin* or the phrases *distant cousin* or *sort of cousin* can cover almost any family relationship.

The [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cousin) gives these definitions

> cousin (also first cousin)
>   1 A child of one's uncle or aunt.
>
> 1.1 A person in one's wider extended family, to whom one is not closely related.
>   ‘she's a distant cousin’
>
> 1.2 A thing related or analogous to another.
>   ‘the new motorbikes are not proving as popular as their four-wheel cousins’
>
> 1.3usually cousins A person of a kindred race or nation.
>   ‘our American cousins’
>
> 1.4historical A title formerly used by a sovereign in addressing another sovereign or a noble of their own country.

Also note that the relationship is not included in the [Table of Kinship and Affinity](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/book-common-prayer/table-kindred-and-affinity) from the 1662 Book of Common Prayer so people having that relationship can marry under Church of England rules.

Comment: You could perhaps use the "removal" as in "cousin one removed", but I have little expertise in that matter.

Comment: @ALambentEye They'd need to trace their nearest common ancestor to use *N-th cousin M-times removed*.

Comment: @ALambentEye Your 'removed' cousin is someone  who is a cousin but of a different generation. Your mother's first cousin (say Ann) is your first cousin once removed. Her son (say Bill) is your second cousin. Also Bill's daughter (say Courtney) is your second cousin once removed and Courtney's son Jack is your second cousin twice removed. (note that removal can be up or down the generations).  'Removal' is not relevant to the OP's relationship to Daniela.